# TLS version differs in different Linux machines

Tags: python, openssl

I have a working code for TLS in python as below:

```
import datetime
import sys
import ssl
from aiosmtpd.smtp import SMTP
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
from aiosmtpd.handlers import Debugging

class Server:
        
        async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
            #some code here
            return "250 OK"

            
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile='cert.pem', keyfile='key.pem')
    
class ControllerStarttls(Controller):
    def factory(self):
        return SMTP(self.handler, enable_SMTPUTF8=True,require_starttls=True, tls_context=context)

controller = ControllerStarttls(Debugging(), hostname='localhost',port=587)

controller.start()
controller.stop()
```

This code when tested on WSL is giving TLSv1.3 but when tested with virtual machine it shows TLSv1.2 . Any idea why the difference is coming in version of TLS.

```
The openssl and python versions on both machines are: 

On WSL(NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)") :

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

On Linux Virtual Machine (NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.4 (Ootpa)")
python --version
Python 3.8.6
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
```

The openssl command used to test above code is :

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect localhost:587
```

Could anyone suggest what could be the reason of the difference in tls version as my requirement is to get TLSv1.3 on Linux virtual machine(RHEL)

Comment: Hi, can you run `rpm -qa "*openssl*"` on both machine to check which package it came from (TLSv1.3 can be deactivated during package build) you may embed a version without it

Comment: @Jaay thanks for reply . I executed the above command on WSL and it did not return anything but on VM RHEL the outcome is :

 rpm -qa "*openssl*"
openssl-pkcs11-0.4.10-2.el8.i686
openssl-devel-1.1.1g-16.el8_4.x86_64
openssl-libs-1.1.1g-16.el8_4.i686
xmlsec1-openssl-1.2.25-4.el8.x86_64
rubygem-openssl-2.1.2-107.module+el8.4.0+10822+fe4fffb1.x86_64
openssl-libs-1.1.1g-16.el8_4.x86_64
openssl-1.1.1g-16.el8_4.x86_64
openssl-pkcs11-0.4.10-2.el8.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following :

On WSL (TLSv1.3 working) you are using the OpenSSL version `1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

On RHEL VM (TLSv1.2 working) you are using OpenSSL version `1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020`

The FIPS version is FIPS140-2 compliant, this means it can only use FIPS certified algorithms. The TLSv1.3 seems not yet certified so it must be disabled in that package version.

I suggest you to uninstall the OpenSSL FIPS version and use the same version thats working on WSL.

Comment: Thanks @Jaay for pointing out the FIPS version for openssl. So instead of uninstall and reinstall there is an option to disable/enable FIPS on RHEL through command line. In my case I disabled and it worked for me.